# How to prevent html elements from being a part of response in $.ajax success response?

Tags: php, jquery

I am submitting an html form through ajax and printing the errors through the same .php file. My code looks a bit like

1.php

```
<?php
  if(!cond){
    echo "error1"
  }else{
    echo "error2"
  }
?>
<form action="#">
<button> and other elements.
```

Now if i print `$('#err').html(response)` from my `.js` on any error it obviously prints whatever `1.php` has to offer including html button and what not. My problem is I don't want these html entities in my response. I can obviously match for each and every error from `.js` and print them all individually but I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if doing everything in a single file is a requirement, you could just check `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header like this:

```
<?php
  if(!cond){
    echo "error1"
  }else{
    echo "error2"
  }

if (!strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {
    ?>
    <form action="#">
    <button> and other elements.
    <?php
}
```

But a better way to go is to create separate php file which will handle your errors.

Comment: yeah i have created separate files too but this case kinda not allowing that. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can only return an error code and handle it by javascript something like this:

in present.php

```
eval("x=" + response);
if(x.Err=='2')
{
    //show error and ...;
}
```

and in service.php :

```
$Res[Err]=2;
echo json_encode($Res)
```